# Are there issues with a tiny alchemist having a tiny tumor familiar?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, familiars, creature-size, alchemist

So I'm starting a new character, and im planning a Svirfneblin with permanenced Reduce Person (making me tiny sized).

Now my question is about the tumor familar discovery, alowing me to have a tiny/diminutive tumor that can detach and take a form of an animal. Now I'm thinking scorpion which is tiny so by direct wording should be ok.

However is there any issues with taking a familar that is the same size as you are? Thematically it sounds wrong since the "tumor" would be as large as I am.

Comment: You might want to wait a while for more answers to come in before marking one as accepted.  It's been less than an hour.

Comment: It's a good solid answer that provides a couple of scenarios to shoot at my DM. Ultimately it is up to her and am using this more for advice as I'm relatively positive there is no official rules governing this. As such i see no reason why not to accept this answer.

Comment: The general consensus is that even a perfect answer should be left at least 12-24 hours before being accepted. Questions with accepted answers are less likely to be viewed, and there's a chance that someone else who may have a more fitting advice/ruling may now be dissuaded from even reading the question, let alone answering.

Comment: I'm moving the discussion that started up here [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59316/discussion-on-question-by-richard-fitzinwell-are-there-issues-with-a-tiny-alchem).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *familiar* is a **tumor** while inside your body, not a creature . So, unlike equipment, which are carryed or wielded, the creature is part of your character as much as your arms and legs. Which means that if the alchemist is reduced in size, the tumor's size is properly adjusted.

It can **detach** itself from your body and become a living creature under your control. So, from the *rules as written*, you can have a Tiny tumor familiar while being a Tiny creature yourself.

As GM, i would give the player two options:

- First, that since you are both two different creatures, you would have to also permanently reduce your tumor familiar, or pick a diminutive familiar instead. Otherwise, whenever you are both merged together, the result would maybe cause some sort of physical penalties, and definitely cause social penalties.
- Second, the familiar and the alchemist are one creature while the tumor is attached, so anything affecting the alchemist would affect the familiar. But once the familiar detached from him, it is now a separate creature and none of the spells affecting the alchemist would be affecting the familiar.

(PS: *Do not look for images of large tumors on google.*)